# npn switching an pnp with dual led

Tags: led, transistors

im trying to use a 0-7V control signal to switch an NPN controlling a LED but then using collector of the NPN to switch a PNP. So when control V is low NPN LED is on and PNP LED is off and when control V is High NPN LED is off and PNP LED is on. Is the below circuit a good way of doing this? i have imagined this circuit in my head and cant find anything similar, maybe for good reason?

[image]

Comment: That circuit will turn both on and off at the same time. You need one NPN for the red LED and you need your whole circuit - NPN and PNP - without the red LED to switch the green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your circuit will turn both LEDs on or both LEDs off.

This will solve that:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8rCqH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: this looks great too. will test both out. many thanks!

Comment: I can guarantee you that this one will suit you better than Rohat's one as his one is just a voltage buffer. This one has gain making it switch in a nicer way.

Comment: This one is better than mine, of course. As I said before, I thought that the input has the same level as Vcc.

Comment: that really is a lovely circuit! many thanks to you both, i can now see why mine didnt work in the first place!

Comment: Lovely and simple as well :-) Notice how it is basically 2 times the same thing *simplicity is the ultimate sophistication*

Comment: When Vin  = 0, Q1 is off but LED D1 is also on because current flows from VDD -> D1 -> R1 -> R3 -> Vbe of Q2. This will turn on Q2 and D2 is also on. So both transistors will be on?

Comment: @anhnha You mean both LEDs will be on, true but since R3 is 10 k ohm the current through D1 will be significantly less than the current through D2 making D1 significantly less bright than D2. If that bothers you you could add a resistor in parallel with D1 to make the voltage across D1 low enough for it not to light up.

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake. I meant both LEDs will be on. I was confused because the OP says that only one LED lights at a time. So I thought that when Vin = 0, D1 should be completely off and D2 is fully on.